# AWS CloudWatch cron events are not accurate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this as my cron expression

```
0/5 * * * ? *
```

and due to the explanation execution should be like this

1. Tue, 24 Nov 2020 10:55:00 GMT Tue
2. 24 Nov 2020 11:00:00 GMT Tue
3. 24 Nov 2020 11:05:00 GMT Tue
4. 24 Nov 2020 11:10:00 GMT Tue

But in the cloudwatch logs I always see something like this

2020-11-24 13:40:27 (UTC+03:00)

or even like this

2020-11-24 13:50:41 (UTC+03:00)

Why is it shifted by 27-50 seconds? Is there any reliable solution for running lambdas exactly on time (apart from AWS cloudwatch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reliable solution for running lambdas exactly on time?

Sadly, its not possible. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) explain this:

> CloudWatch Events **does not provide second-level precision** in schedule expressions. The finest resolution using a cron expression is a **minute**. Due to the distributed nature of the CloudWatch Events and the target services, the delay between the time the scheduled rule is triggered and the time the target service honors the execution of the target resource might be several seconds. Your scheduled rule is triggered **within that minute**, but not on the precise 0th second.

Comment: Is there any other services in aws apart from cloudwatch that will let me to run my events?

Comment: @ЯктенсТид Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any such service. Probably you would have to run your own cron on some instance for more precision.